# Suggest a product X on a lower price when product Y is in cart

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, liquid

In Shopify, when cart has item.product_id == 8078327054657, a form will show suggesting to add item.product_id == 8095240388929. However, it doesn't seem to add the item and only checks out when I click the 'Add' button.
I have included the Liquid and HTML codes for the form and the JS codes for the product to be added to cart when button is clicked. It's basically an upsell. Please help me make it work. Thanks

````
           <div class="cart--upsell-es">          
                      {% if cart.item_count > 0 %}
                          {% for item in cart.items %}
                                {% if item.product_id == 8078327054657 %}
                                {% assign in_cart = true %}
                                      {% endif %}
                          {% endfor %}
                      {% endif %}
                  
                      {% if in_cart %}
                        <div class="cart--upsell-es">                 
                          <div style="padding: 20px 0">
                            <p stye="text-align:center; font-weight:800">Upgrade and Save $41</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="upsell-wrapper">
                            <form
                              id="upsell-form"
                              action="/cart/add"
                              method="post"
                              enctype="multipart/form-data">
                              <input
                                type="hidden"
                                name="id"
                                value="8095240388929" />
                              <input
                                type="hidden"
                                name="quantity"
                                value="1" />
                              <img              src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0699/3615/2897/files/DTB-BEIGE-min.png?v=1674021338"
                                width="50px"
                                height="50px" />
                              <label for="upsell">Double Trouble Bundle</label>
                              <button
                                id="upsell-btn"
                                type="submit"
                                value="Add">Add</button>
                            </form>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      {% endif %}
                  </div>   
    ```
    ```
    <script>
     
      if (theme.settings.cart_type === "drawer") {
      document.getElementById("upsell-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
        var form = document.querySelector("cart--form");
        var formData = new FormData(form);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "/cart/add.js");
        xhr.onload = function() {
          var item = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr2.open("POST", "/cart/change.js");
          xhr2.onload = function() {
            var item2 = JSON.parse(xhr2.responseText);
            console.log(item2);
          };
          xhr2.send(JSON.stringify({quantity: 0, id: 8078327054657}));
        };
        xhr.send(formData);
      });
      }
    </script>
    ```
````

Comment: In your form, you should post your request to `cart/add.js`. Since you have an `action` and the button is linked to the form, clicking on it will submit the form before triggering you onClick event listener. If you want to use your event listener, remove the `action` attribute from the form. As well as the `type` attribute from the button. That way, clicking the button will trigger your event callback and nothing else.

Comment: Hi Genevive, It's still not working. I don't see the item adding to the cart at all. When I click on the 'add' button, it goes to checkout page directly without the item. When adding the bundle, I want to still stay on the same cart (drawer view) and customer can continue shopping. I'm using Blockshop theme, here's the link for their documentation...
https://support.troopthemes.com/guide/js-guide-for-devs/